# How do I assign an assembly name in an Azure Pipeline with Azure PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working on translating a PowerShell script that was written by someone else, into an Azure Build Pipeline. I'm just learning Azure Pipelines. When I run the pipeline I get the following error message:

> Cannot set "AssemblyName" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties

The problem is we've got to sign the assembly so we can include a certification on the resulting application, which is a WPF app.

I've tried searching for the error, but only got results related to .NET Reflection. Here's the Azure PowerShell pipeline task, with the code from the old TFS build to sign the assembly. I made one substitution by including `$(Build.BuildId)`, other than that the code is what's used in the TFS build. Here's the task's code:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Enterprise(/* removed */)'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      $config = ls -recurse "ACDC.csproj" | select -First 1
      
      $xml = [xml]""
      $xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true
      $xml.Load($config)
      $xml.Project.PropertyGroup |? AssemblyName |% {$_.AssemblyName=$env:Binaries}
      $xml.Save($config)
      
      $files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse AssemblyInfo.cs
      foreach ($file in $files){
         $content = Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 $file
         $content = $content -replace '(?<=Assembly(File)?Version\(")(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.\d+)',"`$2.`$3.$(Build.BuildId))`$5";
         Set-Content $file -Encoding UTF8  -Value $content
      }
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error? here? `$xml.Project.PropertyGroup |? AssemblyName |% {$_.AssemblyName=$env:Binaries}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot set "AssemblyName" because only strings can be used as values to set XmlNode properties

I could reproduce this issue. The root cause of this issue is that you haven't set the **variable name: Binaries**.

To solve this issue, you could try the following sample:

Yaml sample:

```
variables:
- name: Binaries
  value: test

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: kevin0322
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
           $config = ls -recurse "WPFRssFeedReader.csproj" | select -First 1
           
           $xml = [xml]""
           $xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true
           $xml.Load($config)
           $xml.Project.PropertyGroup |? AssemblyName |% {$_.AssemblyName=$env:Binaries}
           $xml.Save($config)
           
           $files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse AssemblyInfo.cs
           foreach ($file in $files){
              $content = Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 $file
              $content = $content -replace '(?<=Assembly(File)?Version\(")(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)(\.\d+)',"`$2.`$3.$(Build.BuildId))`$5";
              Set-Content $file -Encoding UTF8  -Value $content
           }
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: 3.1.0
```

Classic Editor:

You need to define the variable in Variables tab.

[image]